# Stopping Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have launched Amazon ec2 m1.small instance with 30GB standard storage. I have installed mongodb and tomcat in /home/ec2-user/ dir.

When I stop my instance will these files get deleted or will I be able to access it when I start the instance again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard data storage is ephemeral. It means the data would be deleted if you terminate the instance.
To keep the data intact, you can use ELASTIC BLOCK STORE (EBS):

1. Attach EBS to your instance (From AWS Management Console)
2. Mount EBS from your instance (From SSH)
3. Transfer required data to EBS drive (From SSH)

Then you can use this EBS any number of times with any other EC2 instance by following the above steps.

Refer: http://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start

Answer (score 1):

If you used EBS storage, nothing will get deleted when you stop an instance. If you have enabled instance storage and you are storing data on those volumes, then they will be deleted if you stop your instance.

If you use the default Amazon Linux AMIs, you wont have instance storage enabled unless you intentionally enable it.